# How to import python module running script in docker container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-import

I need to run python script in the docker container. This script has import of the **psutil** module. I created image and after running it I'm getting error:

```
File "/usr/src/app/metrics.py", line 1, in <module>
   import psutil
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'
```

Locally my script works cause i installed this module through "python -m pip install psutil" command. I've tried to simulate this action in dockerfile through: `"CMD python -m pip install psutil"` but it doesn`t work. What am i doing wrong?
Dockerfile content:

```
FROM python:3.8.2-buster
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY metrics.py .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
CMD python -m pip install psutil
CMD python /usr/src/app/metrics.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/ "There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect."

Maybe you just want to install `psutil` using another `RUN`?

```
FROM python:3.8.2-buster
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY metrics.py .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python -m pip install psutil
CMD python /usr/src/app/metrics.py
```